# Make changes to arguments visible (reflected) outside the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I've got a function:

```
function filterArraysByKeyArray(key, value)
{
  function check(elt, i) { return value === key[i]; }    
  for (var i = 2, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) 
  { 
    arguments[i] = arguments[i].filter(check); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The idea is to modify arrays by key array. My test function is:

```
function test_filterArraysByKeyArray()
{
  var key = [1, 0, 1];
  var value = 1;
  var arr1 = ['M', 'not M', 'L'];
  var arr2 = ['Star Wars', 'booo', 'Stat Trek'];

  filterArraysByKeyArray(key, value, arr1, arr2);

  Logger.log(arr1); // [M, not M, L]
  Logger.log(arr2); // [Star Wars, booo, Stat Trek]
}
```

I get the origins arrays as a result. I've googled this and found out:

> Changes to arguments are not visible (reflected) outside the function.

How do I modify actual passed arguments?

Notes:

1. Google Sheets Script does not support new ECMA standards (`=>`)
2. I need to be able to pass any number of arrays inside a function `filterArraysByKeyArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating *new* arrays, you'll have to have a way to give those arrays back to the calling code. The two standard ways to do that are:

1. Use a return value
2. Use a mutable object

Here's #1, where we return an array of the arrays:

```js
function filterArraysByKeyArray(key, value)
{
  var result = [];
  function check(elt, i) { return value === key[i]; }    
  for (var i = 2, l = arguments.length; i < l; ++i)
  { 
    result.push(arguments[i].filter(check)); 
  }
  return result;
}

function test_filterArraysByKeyArray()
{
  var key = [1, 0, 1];
  var value = 1;
  var arr1 = ['M', 'not M', 'L'];
  var arr2 = ['Star Wars', 'booo', 'Stat Trek'];

  var arrays = filterArraysByKeyArray(key, value, arr1, arr2);
  arr1 = arrays[0];
  arr1 = arrays[1];

  console.log(arrays[0]);
  console.log(arrays[1]);
}

test_filterArraysByKeyArray();
```

Here's #2, using an array (arrays are mutable objects):

```js
function filterArraysByKeyArray(key, value, arrays)
{
  function check(elt, i) { return value === key[i]; }    
  for (var i = 0, l = arrays.length; i < l; ++i)
  { 
    arrays[i] = arrays[i].filter(check); 
  }
  return 0;
}

function test_filterArraysByKeyArray()
{
  var key = [1, 0, 1];
  var value = 1;
  var arrays = [
    ['M', 'not M', 'L'],
    ['Star Wars', 'booo', 'Stat Trek']
  ];

  filterArraysByKeyArray(key, value, arrays);

  console.log(arrays[0]);
  console.log(arrays[1]);
}

test_filterArraysByKeyArray();
```